# Creating a wallet from the command line using monero-cli command?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, php

I'm writing up a php script and I want it to execute a monero-wallet-cli command to create a wallet from my private key. I tried to do this via the command line with monero-wallet-cli, but its in interactive mode and I want to be able to stream line this with php where I can pass in a private key and other parameters.

This is all for internal use so its not exposed to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `monero-wallet-rpc` calling it's `create_wallet` method. https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet